# MySQL insert into unless col1 and col2 are both the same then update another column

Tags: php, mysql

For example...

My table is setup like gameid - userid - rating

When someone submits a rating, I want it to do an insert. But, if the userid and gameid are already together...I want it to just update the rating.

But if maybe that user id is just paired up with another gameid then that's fine go ahead and make a new row.

I'm sure this is out there, I just don't really know how to word what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a composite [`UNIQUE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) on `(gameid, userid)`, then use a query like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`gameid`, `userid`, `rating`)
VALUES (..., ..., ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `rating` = ...
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for MySQL's `REPLACE INTO` functionality. Docs are here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html